# How to create an enum and iterate over it

Tags: loops, go, enums

I'm trying to replicate the Java enums in Go. I would like to define an enum and then iterate over it to do some validations. Something like this in java

```
public enum Direction {
   NORTH,
   NORTHEAST,
   EAST,
   SOUTHEAST,
   SOUTH,
   SOUTHWEST,
   WEST,
   NORTHWEST
}
```

And the I would like to iterate over it, like this:

```
for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
  // do what you want
}
```

Is there a similar way to achieve this in Golang, I'm thinking in using structs but I don't think it's the best way.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever finish writing your chess program? :)

Answer (score 13):

Go doesn't have an equivalent to Java's Enums, but usually [`iota`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota) comes handy when you want to create "enum-like" constants.

Your example may be described like this:

```
type Dir int

const (
    NORTH Dir = iota
    NORTHEAST
    EAST
    SOUTHEAST
    SOUTH
    SOUTHWEST
    WEST
    NORTHWEST
    dirLimit // this will be the last Dir + 1
)
```

And then to iterate over all directions (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/azPEcyTw6RQ)):

```
for dir := Dir(0); dir < dirLimit; dir++ {
    // do what you want
}
```

Also see: [Go Wiki: Iota](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Iota)

For advanced use and tricks with `iota`, see these answers:

[How to skip a lot of values when define const variable with iota?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57053373/how-to-skip-a-lot-of-values-when-define-const-variable-with-iota/57053431#57053431)

[Enumerating string constants with iota](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52208395/enumerating-string-constants-with-iota/52208684#52208684)

Comment: As we used to do in C :-)

Answer (score 1):

The proper answer is [already presented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64178235/6065134). I just want to add that if for some reason you don't want to see `dirLimit` in enum values, it can be replaced by such helper method:

```
type Dir int

const (
    NORTH Dir = iota
    NORTHEAST
    EAST
    SOUTHEAST
    SOUTH
    SOUTHWEST
    WEST
    NORTHWEST
)

func (d Dir) Ok() bool {
    switch d {
    case NORTH,
        NORTHEAST,
        EAST,
        SOUTHEAST,
        SOUTH,
        SOUTHWEST,
        WEST,
        NORTHWEST:
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

`Ok()` returns true if the value is presented in enum. It allows to iterate over enum in the following way:

```
for dir := Dir(0); dir.Ok(); dir++ {
    fmt.Println(dir)
}
```

Here is a link to a [full example in Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/x4FJFXWPyDT).

I also recommend adding [exhaustive linter](https://github.com/nishanths/exhaustive) to your project. It will check if all constants are presented in switch statements. In this way, the build fails if someone introduces a new enum value and forgets to add it into `Ok()` method. Mentioned linter can be used with [golangci-lint](https://golangci-lint.run/usage/linters/#exhaustive) tool.